# Is the United States selective in its support of human rights in other countries?

Tags: united-states, foreign-policy, human-rights

It is common for the US government to make statements condemning what it considers to be human rights abuses in other countries.

This happens frequently with Russia, China, Iran, etc. But it seems to happen less frequently with India, Israel, Saudi Arabia, etc.

Why is this?

Comment: I don't know about India, but the US is *very* close to Israel and Saudi Arabia, especially Israel.

Comment: First, can you give a non-controversial definition of "human rights"?

Comment: The definition for the purposes of this question is when the US issues a condemnation and declares it to be one about human rights.

Comment: @klojj - I made the question a little bit clearer, but it lacks at least one citation to confirm that indeed US is favoring some countries when it comes to human rights. Otherwise the main close reason can be easily invoked ("The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is the United States selective in its support of human rights?

Yes.

> Why is this?

"India, Israel, Saudi Arabia, etc." is a (non-exhastive) list of US military allies.

"Russia, China, Iran, etc." is a (non-exhastive) list of nations the US views as enemies.

Comment: Can you actually supply some data for the first part? I mean, I do think that you're right about the realpolitik of the situation, but something beyond a 'yes' would improve this

Comment: @Displayname It's the pattern of behaviour noted in the question. The title asks "Is this... " and the body asks "This pattern appears..." and "Why"

Comment: The pattern of behaviour is quoted with no sources either...

Answer (score 0):

More to the point, the US doesn't even have domestic human rights law. US law is structured around *constitutional rights* and *civil rights* legal theory. The practical difference is that these only apply to citizens whereas human rights apply to all humans, and this allows the US to treat non-US nationals within its borders in ways that would not be legal under European human rights law.

Other examples include the US being the only country not to have ratified the "UN Convention on the Rights of the Child".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: This is false. Constitutional rights appy to non-US Nationals, short those specifically needing enfranchisement.

Comment: In the technical sense there are procedural rules regarding what a person does and does not have a right to when in US jurisdiction that the EU may not allow, but countries in the EU also have procedural rules that would violate the US Constitution.  I'm not really sure how it's relevant anyway.